# Do unstarted, discarded lazy asyncs cause a memory leak?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Suppose I hold a reference to a `CoroutineScope`, and create a large number of coroutines with `async(CoroutineStart.LAZY) { ... }`.  Suppose I also never use/await many or all of the resulting `Deferred`s.

Does this create a memory leak?  Does the `CoroutineScope` hold a reference to the unstarted child Deferreds?  The presence of the member `val Job.children : Sequence<Job>` suggests it might be, but perhaps there's something going on with the state transition between NEW and ACTIVE that I'm missing.  I glanced at the source, but it's of course pretty hard to follow.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but I would certainly assume that the scope holds references to all child *jobs* via the job's hierarchy. This allows the scope to cancel all children. So yes I would say you leak memory if you don't cancel them.

Comment: I don't see any issue here. There's no reason why lazily started jobs should be garbage collected without user interaction. If you're concerned about it, rethink how you scope and cancel your work (maybe you need some scopes nested in your main scope).

Comment: I lean toward agreement -- this isn't my own issue, but an issue for my organization -- but I also don't think I actually see any reason why lazily started jobs _shouldn't_ be garbage collected if all other strong references to them are discarded, and I'm also firmly of the opinion that it's good to prevent accidental memory leaks.

Comment: As far as I'm aware whenever you create jobs it's your responsibility to hold their reference or at least control their parent scope properly. Pumping a ton of lazy never-to-be-started jobs into single coroutine scope is actually a design error. It would make little sense to burden common implementation of scope with an expensive (and probably not even correct) reference-count based cleanup mechanisms.

Comment: Why reference count?  Weak references, or even simply only adding references in the transition from NEW to ACTIVE state, would do fine.

Answer (score 1):

Experimental verification suggests that yes, unstarted asyncs do leak in that way.  I could imagine ways that might be addressed, but at least today with coroutines 1.7.1, that is a strong reference that could result in leaks.